# Sync Times between ACtive Directory & XServe

Tags: active-directory, osx-server

I am looking for some advice or a script that will allow me to sync times between an Active Directory 2003 Server and a Snow Leopard XServe Server. What I have is an issue where the xserve cannot bind to active directory as the clocks are over 5 minutes out.

Does anyone know if a script can be sent between the two machines or any solution that will keep the clocks in sync?

Many Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Active Directory, then the domain controller should be acting as an NTP Server, which [your OS X box can use](http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/1660) to synchronize its time.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for that I have set the time on the OSX server to go direct to the Active Directory box for it's time and all users now connecting and server now binding again. I have also added an apple script to check and update the date/time in-case this ever happens again.